# Project/Task management software? (hosted on-site, with localized russian interface)

Tags: task-management

I am currently researching what project/task management software is available on the market.
My requirements are:

1. solution needs to be hosted on *my* server, located on-site;
2. it should be possible to switch interface language to russian (since all of employers are russians);
3. it should not be software oriented (in terms of bugs, features, improvements).

If you know anything that can help me, please leave a comment or an answer!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are to develop it or want to use readymade online solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Project Management Standard](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/default.aspx) software by Microsoft Project 2010. This software gives managers an easy way to handle projects. They've made a lot of changes to their visuals and I've noticed that this project manager software has given much higher productivity rates.

Comment: This may be a solution. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

you may give [TeamLab](http://www.teamlab.com/) a try - it is offered as open source & AMI solution, so you may install it on your server, the software has russian localization and you may switch the interface, in addition it's feaures permit TeamLab to be used in software development sphere.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you're associated with TeamLab or not. An upfront disclosure of that would be nice if you are though - it's a very fine line between spam and helpful for things like this where you've promoted TeamLab in 3 out of 3 posts.

Comment: thank you, really not intended to spam

Answer (score 0):

I dunno how good the Russian translation is nowadays, but [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is awesome.

1. Easy to install

   - http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine
   - www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine
2. Flexible
3. Easy to translate
4. Great community

Comment: I took a look at RedMine, but it looks very software oriented bug-tracking system. Not a task management system. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I really love  [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/)

It's also the only system I know which supports Evidence Based Scheduling

I don't know if it supports russian, but perhaps you can ask their support ?

Comment: Actually I already emailed them my question about Russian language yesterday. Still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

We've developed a task and meeting management application for non-IT people (although some dev teams are using it as well) called PriorityCentre https://mijura.com/.

We have the option to host our software onsite on request but we don't support any other languages besides english.  However if you are still looking in a few months then we might :)